# How to use a non-443 port with https?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, centos-6

I can't get https to work on port 3000. Here's my specific situation:

- I have my own VPS running Centos6/Apache.
- I am using [botkit-starter-slack](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-slack) to run a bot from my server.
- I have SSL certs that pass [SSLLabs tests](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) via port 443 with apache listening.
- My bot runs on port 3000, per botkit's recommendation, which is a port I have opened and successfully works via http.

If I load a regular webpage with http**s** (apache, 443), it does fine. If I go to the bot's port 3000 page with http, it works fine. I went ahead and did cURL's on everything relevant. Every url worked fine except for, not surprisingly, the https one with port 3000. I got a `(35) SSL Connect` error.

So I can't get the bot to respond to https on port 3000 (which happens to be necessary for Slack's Events API).

[Here are screenshots of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QQK6.jpg)

- I'm relatively new but I've gotten mixed messages about whether a port can be used for http and https. Can anyone shed light on what standard operating procedure should be here?
- If a port has to be either http OR https, how would I go about making my port 3000 https as opposed to http?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use SSL and non-SSL on the same port. I bet, if you change the non-SSL to 3001 or the SSL one to 3001, it will work.

Comment: Gotcha. Once I figure out how to do that, I'll update! Thanks.

Comment: If port 443 already works, you can of course also open port 3000 on your router and forward it to your pc's port 443. Then you got it sorted too. The reason to not use port 443 publicly, is because it is a widely used port. Unless you want to use other stuff on your system that could be using port 443 too. In that case, you really do need to switch.